# Android DX on a Mac

Tags: java, android, macos

I'm trying to develop an app that displays icons of simple games, when the icon is clicked the game is dynamically loaded from a jar file and run. The games are loaded as plug in so that more games can be added without recompiling the main app.

The games are very simple children's games so the interface to the plug in limited to things like render, touch down, etc.

I'm using **`LibGdx`** as this will allow me to run the app on multiple platforms. I have already got this working on the desktop PC so my idea for the plug ins works.

However I'm now trying to get this to work on the Android simulator but this requires the plug in jar files to be converted to dx format. There are a few posting on how to do this but I cannot get any to work.

The part that I'm currently stuck on is getting the dx converter to work, the line I'm trying is:

```
dx --dex --verbose --output=classes.dex com/playtime/games/Crows.class
```

This throws an exception :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: --verbose: file not found
```

.. exception dump stuff

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: --output=classes.dex: file not found
```

.. exception dump stuff

2 errors; aborting
..

I'm using a Mac to do this, I have tried this on Windows and it does not give the exception.

I really want to get this working on the Mac.

Any ideas anybody

Comment: Does this path exist? classes.dex com/playtime/games/  (/ is a folder delimiter in OSX)

Comment: I've figured out the error at last. I'm using TestEdit on the Mac to create a bash script. For some reason this keeps changing the double - to a single one. I was just adding an extra -. Now all I have to do is stop TextEdit modifiying my text..

Answer (score 0):

This is question was asked a couple of years ago, and I come to here because I'm facing the same error.

I solved this issue simple put your class file to the folder where the dx is.

for example, some path like SDK/platform-tools/ or /out/host/linux-x86/bin.

I think the error message is useless and even misleading. I hope this may help somebody who is facing the same situation like me.